# Unicode non-breaking space is not considered white space?

Tags: apex, string, regular-expressions

Can anyone confirm that Unicode \u00A0 non-breaking space is not considered "whitespace" by Apex and is not detected by trim(), deleteWhitespace, or regex?  I'm surprised by regex since I though \s was supposed to include non-breaking spaces.

Of the methods below, only replaceAll with the character code works.

```
String x = '\u00A0' + 'Test';
String y = x.unescapeUnicode();
system.debug('### y trim length: ' + y.trim().length());
system.debug('### y deleteWhitespace length: ' + y.deleteWhitespace().length());
system.debug('### y replaceall regex length: ' + y.replaceAll('\\s', '').length());
system.debug('### y replaceall unicode length: ' + y.replaceAll('\\u00A0', '').length());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The non-breaking space is not whitespace, according to Java. Apex Code uses the same rules as the Java [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class, which specifies \s as follows:

```
\s  A whitespace character: [ \t\n\x0B\f\r]
```

Where " " is 0x20, \t is 0x09, \n is 0x0A, \x0B is 0x0B, \f is 0x0C, and \r is 0x0D. No other characters are defined as whitespace, despite Unicode having [a number of them](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html).

Comment: This answer is a little suspect considering the `\s` pattern does match the `\u000A` character.

Comment: @AdrianLarson \u000A == 0x0A == \n. They're all the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You've pretty much confirmed it yourself, but just to be sure there's no oddity around the `length` method, I also checked with this script:

```
system.debug(Pattern.compile('\\s').matcher('\u00A0').find()); // yields false
```

And as additional confirmation, I checked the Unicode line feed character:

```
system.debug(Pattern.compile('\\s').matcher('\u000A').find()); // yields true
```